# Android Drawing/ Painting App Update Immediately?

Tags: java, android, events, canvas, draw

I am writing a simple drawing app. Everything works great, EXCEPT when I draw I can only see it AFTER i stop touching the screen.. I can't see the drawing while i am drawing? Any Ideas?

Here is the onTouchListener:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        currentDrawingPath = new DrawingPath();
        currentDrawingPath.paint = currentPaint;
        currentDrawingPath.path = new Path();
        currentBrush.mouseDown(currentDrawingPath.path, motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());


    }else if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
        currentBrush.mouseMove( currentDrawingPath.path, motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY() );

    }else if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        currentBrush.mouseUp( currentDrawingPath.path, motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY() );


        drawingSurface.addDrawingPath(currentDrawingPath);
        drawingSurface.isDrawing = true;
        undoBtn.setEnabled(true);
        redoBtn.setEnabled(false);
    }
    return true;
}
```

and here is the DrawingPath class:

```
public class DrawingPath {
    public Path path;
    public Paint paint;

    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {  
        canvas.drawPath( path, paint );
     }
}
```

Here is the main XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<com.meadows.collin.touchtopaint.DrawingSurface
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawingSurface" />

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:id="@+id/colorRedBtn"
            android:background="@drawable/red_btn" />

    <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:id="@+id/colorBlueBtn"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_btn" />

    <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:id="@+id/colorGreenBtn"
            android:background="@drawable/green_btn" />

    <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:id="@+id/colorYellowBtn"
            android:background="@drawable/yellow_btn" />       

    <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="U"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:id="@+id/undoBtn" />

    <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="R"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:id="@+id/redoBtn" />

    <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="S"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:id="@+id/saveBtn" />

     <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="P"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:id="@+id/pathBtn" />

     <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="C"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:id="@+id/circleBtn" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use draw(Canvas canvas) in MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE case

Here what I did, tested and result was shown(drawn) every movement:

```
private LinearLayout ll1;
private FrameLayout layout;

private float xAxis = 0;
private float yAxis = 0;

private LinearLayout newLinearLayout;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout01);

    ll1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
    newLinearLayout = ll1;

    ll1.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

public void redraw() {
    mainLayout.removeAllViews();

    newLinearLayout.setPadding((int) xAxis, (int) yAxis, 0, 0);

    mainLayout.addView(newLinearLayout);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        xAxis = event.getX();
        yAxis = event.getY();
        redraw();

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        System.out.println("intermediate finished");

    }
    return true;
}
```

xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Testing" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I dont quite understand this. I have attached my main XML file, what in mainLayout and newLinearLayout?

Comment: mainLayout is the main layout like a kind of dash board and the newLinearLayout is being established with every move that will show the changes(ones you draw) and you then delete the old layout, so at the end you still get 2 layouts - one main and one new layout with changes. It might put pressure to a processor, but I have tested it in different ways and device's processor can handle it without a problem

Comment: so, what kind of type is mainLayout? is it a Linear Layout? and is newLinearLayout just newLinearLayout= new LinearLayout(this); ?? Im confused a little

Comment: I pasted the whole program in the post, you can just try it out, play with it, change some values and i hope you will get the idea how it works, so it will help you to solve your case

Comment: remember, that the TextView that is allowed to move can be almost any component from all the androids widgets set and the whole bunch of xml components in this example are not static, you may use whatever you want, just then programmatically specify which part you would like to move